# Autofilling columns in attribute table based on values of another cell in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression

I am working with vegetation types within a project site. Each vegetation type belongs to a broader group termed a `"vegetation group"`. For example, in the screen shot below, I have the two vegetation types 'WC1' and 'WC2' which belong to the 'Wet Coniferous Forest Group'.

Is there a way by expression to populate a new column with the the appropriate vegetation group based on the vegetation types in a column? In this example, all 'WC1' and 'WC2' would be in the 'Wet Coniferous Forest Group' which would be in a new column.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) with a [CASE](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#case)-statement. The expression looks like this, where `"vegetation_type"` is the name of the field containing the `WC1`, `WC2` values:

```sql
case 
    when "vegetation_type" in ('WC1', 'WC2') then 'Wet Coniferous Forest Group'
end
```

Before the `end` statement, you can add as many similar `when ... then` statements as you like:

```sql
when "vegetation_type" in ('WC3', 'WC4') then 'Another Group'
```

You can also add an `else` statement that returns the output in all other cases,  something like `else 'other'`. Add this after the last `when` statement, before `end`:

```sql
case 
    when "vegetation_type" in ('WC1', 'WC2') then 'Wet Coniferous Forest Group'
    when "vegetation_type" in ('WC3', 'WC4') then 'Another Group'
    else 'other'
end
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this which may work better if you have a dynamic data set, would be to make a look-up table. i.e. a table with two fields type and group and then fill in the table with the actual groups,

```
 type | group
 -----+----------------
 WC1  | Wet Coniferous
 WC2  | Wet Coniferous
 WC3  | Another group
 WC4  | Something else
```

Then you join this table to the existing data set

Comment: I will look into using this solution as well. Thanks